# Grails prevent casceding update with MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, grails, spring-security

I have three Domain Classes(DC) named One,Two & Three.

(DC) One and Three are Persisted to MongoDB whereas (DC) Two is an embedded Class to Class One.

(Class Two is not persisted to MongoDB.)

code:

```
//One.groovy

class One {

    ObjectId id

    List<Two> two

    static hasMany = [two: Two]
    static embedded = ['two']

    static constraints = {
    two nullable: true
    }
}

-------------

//Two.groovy

class Two {
    Three three

    static mapWith = "none"

    static constraints = {
        three nullable: true
    }
}

----------

//Three.groovy

class Three {

    ObjectId id

    String ...
    // some attributes later..

    static hasMany = [....]
    static mappedBy = [...]
    static embedded = [...]

}
```

The problem i am facing is, when i am saving Class One's object, All the Objects of class Three which are there in class Two(as Three three) are being updated in mongoDB.

Proof: (MongoDB Log)

```
2015-07-11T02:32:01.299+0530 [conn113] update database.three query: { 
....many such lines means these are getting updated.
```

**How to prevent this cascading save.**

Configuration:

```
grails 2.4.3
mongodb 2.6.4
```

Plugins:

```
compile ":mongodb:3.0.3"
compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC5"
```

NOTE: not using any Hibernate Plugin

UPDATE: Tried removing

```
 static hasMany = [two: Two]
```

From Class One still i see the logs up three being updated in MongoDB